# Teacher told us we're not allowed to write negative vectors, is this correct or not?

Tags: reference-frames, coordinate-systems, vectors, conventions

The question is a bit vague, so I apologize for that.

To properly explain what I mean, I'll use an example.

Let's say we've got two forces going left and right. $F_1$ is $20 \, \text{N}$, and will be positive. $F_2$ is $10 \, \text{N}$ and will be negative.

To calculate the net force, I've always written it as:

$$
F_{\text{net}} = F_1 - F_2
$$

I then substitute the values and get:

$$
F_{\text{net}} = 20 \, \text{N} - 10 \, \text{N}
$$

However, according to my teacher, this is incorrect and should be done in the following way:

$$
F_{\text{net}} = F_1 + F_2 \quad (\text{with arrows over } F_1 \text{ and } F_2 \text{ indicating the direction})
$$

He then substitutes it like this:

$$
F_{\text{net}} = 20 + (-10)
$$

His argument is that $F_2$ is already a negative value, and writing $-F_2$ will make the negatives cancel. Our entire class has been using the first method for the past two years, but now it's apparently incorrect.

Which method is actually correct?

Answer (score 5):

Your teacher is instructing you to define the vectors in terms of their components,
\begin{align}
\vec F_1 &= \hat x \cdot 20\,\mathrm N
\\
\vec F_2 &= \hat x \cdot (-10\,\mathrm N)
\end{align}
and then to add the *vectors*,
\begin{align}
\vec F_\text{net} &= \vec F_1 + \vec F_2
\\&= \hat x \cdot \left(
20\,\mathrm N - 10\,\mathrm N
\right)
\end{align}
Your instinct is to skip the intermediate definition.

Your approach *only* works for one-dimensional vectors.  If you find yourself adding forces with nonzero components in the $\hat x$, $\hat y$, and $\hat z$ directions, you'll find yourself sticking minus signs in the middle of your vector definitions. That way lies madness.

Your teacher's approach generalizes cleanly to multidimensional vectors.
It is more advanced than your previous approach. Your teacher knows things that you don't. This is normal.

---

> Our entire class has been using the first method for the past two years, but now it's apparently incorrect.

You're in your third year of one-dimensional kinematics? That sounds like torture.

Comment: By international law, only Atwood's Machine is considered torture.

Comment: I just realized it seems like I'm only doing one dimensional kinematics.  We started with two dimensional kinematics earlier this year, the example I gave was just very simple.  By the way, I don't really understand why doing the first method will cause problems in two dimensions, could you maybe provide an example of that?

Comment: @Amanwithabucket When I was teaching I could have come up with three or four examples off the top of my head, but currently I don't have an ensemble of tricky kinematics problems handy — at least, not problems that would fit in a comment. As you move into more complex systems, where Cartesian coordinates are no longer the best fit, you'll want coordinate-independent representations of vector arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the teacher is trying to build a good habit of separating the vector from the representation.

Vectors and numbers are different types of things. One can *represent* vectors well using numbers (as long as one has the right coordinate basis). While in one dimension the difference between a vector and a number is negligible (both are isomorphic, mathematically speaking) this gets messy in two dimensions and more. In a lot of applications one can shift between different representations (x,y-coordinates, polar coordinates, other things) depending on the problem, without changing the vector in question.

In practice, even professional people often adopt sloppy methods that work. But it is good to know that they are sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

You are both right. You should learn what your teacher is talking about. You will need both ways of thinking.

You are thinking of forces like numbers on a number line. Those to the right are + and those to the left are -. You add and subtract numbers like you always have.

Your teacher is thinking of forces like vectors or arrows that point left or right. An arrow has a length and a direction. The length is never negative. You add vectors geometrically by laying them tip to tail to get a vector sum. You subtract a vector by finding the vector in the opposite direction and adding that.

Vectors might seem like overkill for what you are doing. But forces on a plane or in $3$D space can point many directions. You can still add them tip to tail to get a total force.

You can also still use numbers. You need two number lines to make a number plane. So you can convert back and forth between an arrow in a plane and a pair of numbers. You can add pairs of numbers together to get a pair that represents a total vector.

The numbers that make up a vector can be positive or negative. But the length of a vector is never negative.